# How to unset array associative multidimensional if key not same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have data like this :

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [COMPANY_SERVICE_ID] => CS01
        [COMPANY_NAME] => HANOMAN SAKTI PRATAMA, PT - JAKARTA
        [TARIFF_CURRENCY] => IDR
        [SELLING_SERVICE_ID] => SS01
        [CONTAINER_TYPE_ID] => DC
        [SERVICE_NAME] => CONTAINER TRUCKING SERVICE
        [FROM_QTY] => 1
        [TO_QTY] => 100
        [FROM_NAME] => TANJUNG PRIOK
        [FROM_LOCATION_ID] => L096
        [TO_NAME] => BALARAJA
        [TO_LOCATION_ID] => L002
        [RESULT_LOCATION] => Array
            (
                [L001] => Array
                    (
                        [TARIF_20] => 1.500.000,00
                        [TARIF_40] => 1.750.000,00
                        [TARIF_45] => 5.500.000,00
                        [TARIF_4H] => 3.500.000,00
                    )

                [L002] => Array
                    (
                        [TARIF_20] => 500.000,00
                    )

            )

    )
```

i wanna unset value of RESULT_LOCATION if value in RESULT_LOCATION different with value of TO_LOCATION_ID.

What should i do?

i try to remove with code like this :

```
foreach ($hasil_jakarta as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value['RESULT_LOCATION'] as $key1 => $value1) {
            if ($value['TO_LOCATION_ID'] != $value['RESULT_LOCATION'][$key1]) {
                unset($hasil_jakarta[$key]['RESULT_LOCATION'][$key1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

but all value of RESULT_LOCATION deleted. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Loop the array, then loop its sub array `RESULT_LOCATION`. Compare each key from that against the value of `TO_LOCATION_ID` and if you don't find a match by the end of it then delete the array

Comment: how to know what value of $value['RESULT_LOCATION'] if i loop that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to test the value but the key. Then, [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) arrays with different keys.

Here is an example :

```
<?php
$a = array(
        'COMPANY_SERVICE_ID' => 'CS01',
        'COMPANY_NAME' => 'HANOMAN SAKTI PRATAMA, PT - JAKARTA',
        'TARIFF_CURRENCY' => 'IDR',
        'SELLING_SERVICE_ID' => 'SS01',
        'CONTAINER_TYPE_ID' => 'DC',
        'SERVICE_NAME' => 'CONTAINER TRUCKING SERVICE',
        'FROM_QTY' => 1,
        'TO_QTY' => 100,
        'FROM_NAME' => 'TANJUNG PRIOK',
        'FROM_LOCATION_ID' => 'L096',
        'TO_NAME' => 'BALARAJA',
        'TO_LOCATION_ID' => 'L002',
        'RESULT_LOCATION' => array(
                'L001' => array(
                        'TARIF_20' => '1.500.000,00',
                        'TARIF_40' => '1.750.000,00',
                        'TARIF_45' => '5.500.000,00',
                        'TARIF_4H' => '3.500.000,00'
                ),
                'L002' => array(
                        'TARIF_20' => '500.000,00'
                )
        )
);


foreach ($a['RESULT_LOCATION'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $a['TO_LOCATION_ID']) {
        unset($a['RESULT_LOCATION'][$key]);
    }
}
```

The result will be :

```
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [COMPANY_SERVICE_ID] => CS01
    [COMPANY_NAME] => HANOMAN SAKTI PRATAMA, PT - JAKARTA
    [TARIFF_CURRENCY] => IDR
    [SELLING_SERVICE_ID] => SS01
    [CONTAINER_TYPE_ID] => DC
    [SERVICE_NAME] => CONTAINER TRUCKING SERVICE
    [FROM_QTY] => 1
    [TO_QTY] => 100
    [FROM_NAME] => TANJUNG PRIOK
    [FROM_LOCATION_ID] => L096
    [TO_NAME] => BALARAJA
    [TO_LOCATION_ID] => L002
    [RESULT_LOCATION] => Array
        (
            [L002] => Array
                (
                    [TARIF_20] => 500.000,00
                )

        )

)
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I saw your snippet and adapt the loop for your needs :

```
foreach ($hasil_jakarta as $h_j_key => $h_j_value) {
    foreach ($h_j_value['RESULT_LOCATION'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != $h_j_value['TO_LOCATION_ID']) {
            unset($hasil_jakarta[$h_j_key]['RESULT_LOCATION'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Your code was almost good but the unset line was not. In that case, you need to unset a variable from the `$hasil_jakarta` array.

Good luck !

Comment: i try but still doesn't work, please open http://pastebin.com/sPSD0WPA. in that pastebin i have multidimensional array. what's wrong?

Comment: @Four, see my edited answer. The loop must work for your `$hasil_jakarta` array now. Please remember to validate my answer if it fills your needs. ; )